# Multi Step Form on Modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, multi-step

I am trying to use Bootstrap Multi Step Form on Bootstrap Modal. I am trying to use this [Form](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps). My code is like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Multi Step Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        #regForm {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin: 100px auto;
            font-family: Raleway;
            padding: 40px;
            width: 70%;
            min-width: 300px;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        input {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: Raleway;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }

        /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
        input.invalid {
            background-color: #ffdddd;
        }

        /* Hide all steps by default: */
        .tab {
            display: none;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: Raleway;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #prevBtn {
            background-color: #bbbbbb;
        }

        /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
        .step {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbbbbb;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .step.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
        .step.finish {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="home">
            <h2>Multi Step Form</h2>
            <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Open Form
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
                            <h4>1st Step</h4>
                            <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
                            <div class="tab">Name:
                                <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
                                <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab">Contact Info:
                                <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
                                <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab">Birthday:
                                <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
                                <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
                                <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab">Login Info:
                                <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
                                <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword"
                                        type="password"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="overflow:auto;">
                                <div style="float:right;">
                                    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
    }
</script>

</html>
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: x[n] is undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have no HTML element with class `step`, therefore this will return `[]` in `x`

```
var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
```

and when you trying to access index of an empty array its giving this error

```
x[n].className += " active";
```

Answer (score 0):

As was answered earlier on, you'll need a field with class name "step" so as to not return nil.

What I normally do is have a  field that has spans for each step of the form.
And then a JavaScript that switches between each step of the form. A sample is below:

```
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
<span class="step"></span>
</div>
```

Then I have this function in the JavaScript file to switch between steps.

```
function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Hope this gives you further clarity on how to go about it.